Evaluating the integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x+x^2)}{x-x^2}dx$
Evaluating the integral:$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x+x^2)}{x-x^2}dx $$
I've tried substitution, but got $dx=\frac{1-du}{2x}$ and not sure how to proceed.

Cf. this question and this question

@J.W.Tanner This question appears to be a straightforward duplicate of the one you linked---am I missing something?

No, they are the same question. I didn't find it. Thanks!

Also this question
